# SQL with JOIN and WHERE?

Tags: sql

I have been trying to figure this out, but have not been able for the last couple of hours, but can't seem to figure it out.

I have two tables `receipts` and `if_receipts_upl`

```
receipts
-po
-receipt_type

if_receipts_upl
-po
-owner_id
-if_status
-if_date
```

Now I need to write a sql statement that updates if_status for a certain range of dates(if_date), for all receipt_type except IBD

Here what I have tried and it is not working

```
SELECT  r.po,r.receipt_type, ifr.po FROM receipts AS r, if_receipts_upl AS ifr 
INNER JOIN if_receipts_upl
ON r.po=ifr.po AND ifr.owner_id='GIII'  
  AND (ifr.stat_date >='2014-07-01' AND ifr.stat_date   <'2014-08-01') 
ORDER BY ifr.stat_date
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you provide table structure?

Comment: Your syntax has errors. Remove the `, if_receipts_upl AS ifr` and include `AS ifr` after the last reference to `if_receipts_upl`. Right now you have a mixture of join syntax styles and it would be awful (I suspect it's a Cartesian product, if it works at all)

Comment: @user2797021 if these any of these answers were correct you should accept the one that you found to be the most correct by clicking the checkbox underneath the vote number. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that it is because of how you are applying your `where` criteria,  while it is possible to do some of this in a join clause, it can sometimes cause some behavior that you may not have expected, as I think is happening here.

Try this query:

```
SELECT  r.po,r.receipt_type, ifr.po FROM receipts AS r 
INNER JOIN if_receipts_upl AS ifr
ON r.po=ifr.po
WHERE ifr.owner_id='GIII'  
  AND (ifr.stat_date >='2014-07-01' AND ifr.stat_date   <'2014-08-01') 
ORDER BY ifr.stat_date
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
SELECT r.po,
       r.receipt_type, 
       ifr.po 

FROM   receipts AS r 

       INNER JOIN if_receipts_upl ifr ON r.po=ifr.po 

WHERE  ifr.owner_id='GIII'  
       AND ifr.stat_date >= '2014-07-01' 
       AND ifr.stat_date <  '2014-08-01'

ORDER  BY ifr.stat_date
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update (change) the value of if_status you need a slightly different syntax:

```
UPDATE if_receipts_upl                 -- table to update
SET if_status = 'new value'            -- column to change, and new value
FROM if_receipts_upl ifr               
INNER JOIN receipts r ON r.po=ifr.po 
WHERE ifr.owner_id='GIII'              -- where to filter what rows get changed
AND ifr.stat_date >= '2014-07-01' 
AND ifr.stat_date <  '2014-08-01'
AND r.receipt_type <> 'IBD'
```

Answer (score 0):

You specified that you wanted to "update if_status for a certain range of dates(if_date), for all receipt_type except IBD", but the sample code you provided is a *SELECT* statement, not an *UPDATE* statement. Select statements will only return values, they won't update the database. To perform what you are asking, you will need to write an UPDATE statement similar to your select statement that includes the conditions you have specified.

```
UPDATE
    if_receipts_upl
SET
    if_status = -- YOUR UPDATED VALUE HERE
FROM
    if_receipts_upl AS i
    INNER JOIN
    receipts AS r
    ON
        i.po = r.po
WHERE
    i.owner_id = 'GIII'
    AND i.if_date BETWEEN '2014-07-01' AND '2014-08-01'
    AND receipt_type <> 'IBD' -- This fulfills one of the conditions you specify
```